# path:hover will not with the fill attribute set with style="fill:rgb(255,60,60) format

Tags: javascript, svg

```html
<body>
<style>
path:hover{
fill:orange;
}
</style>

<svg width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 102 102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<path d="M24,58a28,28,0,1,1,55,0l21,4a50,50,0,1,0-97,1z" style="fill:rgb(255,60,60)"></path> 
<path  d="M19,16a46,46 0,1,0 62,0l-8,8a34,34 0,1,1-46,0z" fill="rgb(0,255,0)"></path> 
<path d="M46,43v35a28,28 0,0,1-14-49zM54,43v35a28,28 0,0,0 14-49z" fill="#396"></path>
</svg>
</body>
```

if you change the style="fill:rgb(255,60,60)" to style="fill:#ff00ff" it will work

Comment: Your `style` attribute will create a rule more important than the `path:hover`. Either use the `fill` attribute directly (with rgb it works too), either move it to your stylesheet, with a low importance rule.

Comment: actually the question has not been answered I cannot change the attribute assignment I cannot change any of the html not because i don't know how  but because of other issues

Comment: In that case the question has no solution.

Comment: thanks for your comments i get it now